# How to sort a wrapper class list which has a reference to another wrapper in it

Tags: apex, list, wrapper-class, sort

I want to sort a wrapper class list which has a reference to another wrapper in it.I tried implementing Comparable interface for both of class but it is showing error

> One or more of the items in this list is not Comparable.

Please suggest me some way to do this.

i want to sort list by name and number.i will use a field sortBy for this purpose.

```
Class A{

list<WrapperB> listOfB{get;set;}
public A(){
   listOfB.sort();
}
class WrapperB {
String name{get;set;}
public WrapperC ref{get;set;}
}

class WrapperC{
String number;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would write this code:

```
Class A {

    list<WrapperB> listOfB {get;set;}

    class WrapperB implements Comparable {

        String name {get;set;}
        public WrapperC ref {get;set;}

        public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
            WrapperB that = (WrapperB) o;
            if (this.name < that.name) return -1;
            else if (this.name > that.name) return 1;
            else return this.ref.compareTo(that.ref);
        }
    }

    class WrapperC implements Comparable {

        String number;

        public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
            WrapperC that = (WrapperC) o;
            if (this.number < that.number) return -1;
            else if (this.number > that.number) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    } 
}
```

When `WrapperB.name` values are the same, `WrapperC.number` defines the sort order. This code assumes no null values are present.

The original code posted would always NPE because `listOfB` would be null when the constructor ran.

Comment: Yes, it is essential to implement Comparable interface if you are trying to sort a wrapper class.